How to I properly implement C# classes using ASP.NET Core MVC?
The assignment is to create an ASP.NET Core MVC web app that has a Student and a StudentWorker class. You then have the user input the information for a StudentWorker object (id, name, hourly pay, and hours worked). You output the weekly salary (hourlyPay * hoursWorked) to the view, making sure that the hourly pay is in the range (7.25 - 14.75), and the hours worked is in the range (1 - 15).
I created both the Student and StudentWorker classes with no problems, as well as the view (for the most part). I'm pretty sure most of the issues lie in the controller. The ASP.NET Core MVC framework is hard for me to understand, and I'm just trying to complete this C# class.
I'll list the project files below:
Model classes:
namespace FinalProject.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        // Private fields
        private int id;
        private string name;

        // Public property for ID
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        // Public property for Name
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        // Constructors
        public Student(int id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        // Default constructor (demonstrates method overloading)
        public Student()
        {
            id = 0;
            name = "";
        }

        // Method to display student information (overrides default ToString method)
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ($"ID: {ID}, Name: {Name}");
        }
    }

    public class StudentWorker : Student
    {
        // Private fields
        private double hourlyPay;
        private int hoursWorked;

        // Public property for HourlyPay
        public double HourlyPay
        {
            get { return hourlyPay; }
            set
            {
                if (value >= 7.25 && value <= 14.75)
                    hourlyPay = value;
                else
                    hourlyPay = 0;
            }
        }

        // Public property for HoursWorked
        public int HoursWorked
        {
            get { return hoursWorked; }
            set
            {
                if (value >= 1 && value <= 15)
                    hoursWorked = value;
                else
                    hoursWorked = 0;
            }
        }

        // Constructor
        public StudentWorker(int id, string name, double hourlyPay, int hoursWorked)
                    : base(id, name)
        {
            HourlyPay = hourlyPay;
            HoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        }

        // Default constructor (demonstrates method overloading)
        public StudentWorker() : base()
        {
            HourlyPay = 0;
            HoursWorked = 0;
        }

        // Method to calculate weekly salary
        public double WeeklySalary()
        {
            if (HourlyPay == 0 || HoursWorked == 0)
                return 0;

            return HourlyPay * HoursWorked;
        }

        // Method to display student worker information (overrides default ToString method)
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ($"ID: {ID}, Name: {Name}, Hourly Pay: {HourlyPay:C}, Hours Worked: {HoursWorked}, Weekly Salary: {WeeklySalary():C}");
        }
    }
}

View
@model FinalProject.Models.StudentWorker

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Student Worker";
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Worker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Create Student Worker</h2>

<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label">Student ID</label>
        <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Student Name</label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HourlyPay" class="control-label">Hourly Pay</label>
        <input asp-for="HourlyPay" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="HourlyPay" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HoursWorked" class="control-label">Hours Worked</label>
        <input asp-for="HoursWorked" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="HoursWorked" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Weekly Salary</button>
</form>


@if (ViewBag.WeeklySalary != null)
{
    <h3>Weekly Salary: @ViewBag.WeeklySalary</h3>
}

</body>
</html>

Controller
using FinalProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FinalProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: StudentWorker/Create
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: StudentWorker/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(StudentWorker model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Calculate weekly salary
                var weeklySalary = model.WeeklySalary();
                ViewBag.WeeklySalary = weeklySalary;

                // Return view with the weekly salary
                return View(model);
            }

            // If model state is not valid, redisplay the form
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}

I've tried removing the ranges for hourlyPay and hoursWorked, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Again, I'm unfamiliar with writing web apps, and I would greatly appreciate any help :)

"...most of the issues...", "...doesnt seem to do anything..." You'd said what you're trying to accomplish, and you've posted code (though, it's quite a lot and a [mre] would be better), but you haven't said what this code does versus what you expect it to do.

Add break points in the controller and see if you are getting to the break points.  You are making an HTTP connection which has a client and a server.  The controller is the server code.  You are making a HTTP request from the client and using [HttpPost] which indicates that the request has a body.  I do not see the client code where the request is made.  You need to check the response from the request and see what status is being returned.  Normally a good response will contain a 200 OK and a error would normally be a 400/500 status.

@jdweng I added breakpoints to see what is happening to the value of the member variables in my StudetWorker class, and it seems that none of them are being assigned the value that I input, when I run the web app. I don't know what my controller is supposed to look like. Right now I dont have any mention of ID, Name, HourlyPay, or HoursWorked, in the Controller which I'm assuming need to be implemented there, I used ChatGPT to help me thus far FYI. I can get the web app to run just fine, and I can input the values. The problem is it's not assigning my member variables those values.

In .NET we usually don't write the class the way you did. Instead we write like this  public string Name { get; set; } then when you would submit from value try extracting value from the request paramer and bind to your model. This how you should work.

Your client should serialize the student and add the serialized data to the body of the request (the post).  Then the controller should deserialize the body of the request which is the student (the model).  Check you client code to make sure the data is being placed in the model and getting serialized.

@jdweng I do not understand serialization, I'm new to web development.

You do not need to serialize.  You can make the http header Content-Type of the client request "text/html" and then add the html to the body of the request.  Then the controller in the server will automatically handle the html data.

I don't understand what you're asking me to do. Where do I do this, on the View? I don't know how to implement this. I've very new to Web Apps, and my professor didn't do a very good job in explaining how everything works.


I'm pretty sure most of the issues lie in the Controller. The MVC
ASP.NET framework is hard for me to understand, and I'm just trying to
complete this C# class.

Based on your shared code, in .NET or asp.net core or even in C# we write classes with clean getter and setter attribute, not the way you did. Therefore, you are not getting the expected output you are looking for.
In order to implement your requirement, you should have Student and StudentWorker with the model validation annotation like Range, Required to validate your working hours rate and working hours.
In addition to this, you could write the calculate payment method inside that class as well. Finally, return the claculated value to the view if the validation passed.
Let's have a look in practice, how we can implement that in cleaner way.
Model:
public class Student
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StudentWorker : Student
{
    [Required]
    [Range(7.25, 14.75, ErrorMessage = "Hourly pay must be between $7.25 and $14.75")]
    public double HourlyPay { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 15, ErrorMessage = "Hours worked must be between 1 and 15")]
    public int HoursWorked { get; set; }

    public double WeeklySalary()
    {
        return HourlyPay * HoursWorked;
    }
}

Controller:
public class StudentWorkerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new StudentWorker());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CalculatePayment(StudentWorker model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.WeeklySalary = model.WeeklySalary();
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
}

View:
@model StudentWorker

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Student Worker";
}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Create Student Worker</h2>

    <form asp-action="CalculatePayment" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label">Student ID</label>
            <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Student Name</label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="HourlyPay" class="control-label">Hourly Pay</label>
            <input asp-for="HourlyPay" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="HourlyPay" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="HoursWorked" class="control-label">Hours Worked</label>
            <input asp-for="HoursWorked" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="HoursWorked" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate Weekly Salary</button>
    </form>

    @if (ViewBag.WeeklySalary != null)
    {
        <h3>Weekly Salary: $ @ViewBag.WeeklySalary</h3>
    }
</div>

Upate:
Project structure:

Be informed that, Middleware, Enum, services is my custom folder.
Controller:

Model:

View:

Program.cs files is default when the project created. And the routing is also default like below:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
  
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Output:





Note: Above sample denotes one of the apporach in asp.net core. However, there are couple of other way as well. If you want to know, please refer to this offcial document for Model validation. and additional sample.

It still doesn't work. I get this error: This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405. When I run it in debug mode, it never even get's to the breakpoints. I'm guessing that's because when I hit "Calculate Weekly Salary" I get that error message.

As per the error message 405 indicates, your submit form request method and the controller method http verb (GET, POST) doesn't match. Please double check if those are correct and also check the class defination as well. Check the browser netweork trace, that will give you more details. In addition, if you directly copy and past my code it would work accooringly,  once you would able to make it work, then you can start refactoring your code.

I think the problem is the file names, and where the files are located. Can you show me your solution explorer with the folders expanded? I know I'm almost there, because I did some more research. and I'm understanding MVC better. Also, what does the bottom of your Progam.cs look like? (since that's where the route is)

Its a normal asp.net core MVC project, the .NET version was 8 and I will update the answer with project screenshot and progra.cs file. Usually, the controller should in controller folder and the views in view folder.

Check the updated answer, let me know if you'were able to resolve.

I finally got it to work!!! I had to make some modifications, and my Program.cs file is actually different than yours. Thank you for all you help, I'm so greatful! :)
